# How to form this WHERE clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

It turns out I have a data table that goes something like this:

```
┌─────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ month (integer) │ year (integer) │ academic year (varchar) │
├─────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│ 1               │ 2018           │ 2017-2018               │
│ 12              │ 2018           │ 2017-2018               │
│ 3               │ 2019           │ 2018-2019               │
│ 3               │ 2019           │ 2015-2016               │
│ 8               │ 2019           │ 2018-2019               │
└─────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

Please notice the differing data types.

**My goal is to obtain the rows such that the month and the year form a date that belongs to the academic year in the same row.** The academic year begins in September (9) and ends in August (8). For example, the third rown shouldn't be included in the results since 12/2018 doesn't belong to 2017-2018 but 2018-2019.

My `WHERE` clause should be something like:

- `CONVERT(varchar(10), year-1) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10), year) = academic_year` in case month is lesser than 9,
- and `CONVERT(varchar(10), year) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10), year+1) = academic_year` otherwise.

Of course this code doesn't make sense. I need to know:

- how to convert between data types,
- how to concatenate attributes and constants.

Is it possible? Any idea?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the schema? What database is this?

Comment: No possible changes!

Comment: I don't understand this data. What is month telling me? What is year telling me? What is academic year telling me? What result are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

First, convert `month` and `year` to an actual [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). There's many ways to do this with your data. Using [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to put the `month` and `year` into a format MySQL recognizes as a [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) is one.

```
date( concat(year,"-",month,"-",1) ) as created_at;
```

This turns `year` and `month` into a single date starting at the beginning of the month.

Then split `academic_year` into two aliased columns. We can take advantage that the format is always `YYYY-YYYY` (you can verify this with `where academic_year not rlike '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$'`) and use `left` and `right` to get the first and last 4 characters.

```
left(academic_year, 4), right(academic_year, 4)
```

Turn those into dates for the start and end of the academic year.

```
date( concat(left(academic_year, 4),"-","09","-","01") ) as start_period
date( concat(right(academic_year, 4),"-","08","-","31") ) as end_period
```

Now you can work with `created_at`, `start_period`, and `end_period` using the [`between`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) comparison.

```
where created_at between start_period and end_period
```

Put it all together...

```
select
    date( concat(year,"-",month,"-",1) ) as created_at,
    date( concat(left(academic_year, 4),"-","09","-","01") ) as start_period,
    date( concat(right(academic_year, 4),"-","08","-","31") ) as end_period
from stuff
where created_at between start_period, end_period;
```

Note how easy the query becomes *after* you've done the work to convert to proper `date` types. Rather than doing ad-hoc parsing for yours particular need, it's best to normalize to real `date` types and use the built in MySQL date functions.

---

If at all possible, you should change the schema to store directly as `date` types. Not only will it make things much simpler, but also faster as the date columns can be indexed for fast searching. Even if you can't do it, it's good to see how data like this should be stored.

Leave the old columns in place for backwards compatibility if you must, just add new ones.

```
add column stuff created_at date not null;
add column stuff academic_year_start date not null;
add column stuff academic_year_end date not null;
```

Populate the new columns.

```
update stuff
set created_at = date( concat(year,"-",month,"-",1) ),
    academic_year_start = date( concat(left(academic_year, 4),"-","09","-","01") ),
    academic_year_end   = date( concat(right(academic_year, 4),"-","08","-","31") ) as end_period
```

And put indexes on them.

```
create index stuff_created_at on stuff (created_at);
create index academic_year on stuff (academic_year_start, academic_year_end);
```

And once that's done your query, and anything like it, becomes very simple and very fast.

```
select *
from stuff
where created_at between academic_year_start and academic_year_end;
```

Because information about an academic year will be duplicated many times, the second redesign would be to move the academic year information into its own table and refer to it as a foreign key.